# Bash script in Ant

Tags: bash, ant

I have script for asterisk

```
./configure --prefix=/home/some/path
```

I want to execute this script from `build.xml` file

this version does not work

```
<exec dir="${asterisk.dir}" executable="./configure">
    <arg line=" --prefix=/home/some/path"/>
</exec>
```

Can anybody help me?

Comment: How *exactly* does it "not work"?

Comment: Is the configure script executable?  Does it work if you remove "./"?

Comment: Try removing the space before `--`.

Comment: @Kevin That doesn't make a difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference between you command line and the Ant script is the working directory. One is the current one, the other is the asterisk one.

Probably you just want to do:

```
<exec dir="${basedir}" executable="${basedir}/configure">
    <arg line="--prefix=/home/some/path"/>
</exec>
```